# Delete an embed when a reaction is added

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {

  if (message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === process.env.MODO)) {

    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    // Parse Amount
    const amount = !!parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) ? parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) : parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[2])
    if (!amount) return message.reply('Vous devez spécifier un montant à supprimer !');
    if (!amount && !user) return message.reply('Vous devez spécifier un utilisateur et le montant, ou juste une quantité de messages à purger !');
    if (amount > 100) return message.reply('Malheureusement, discord ne permet pas la Suppression de plus de 100 messages en une fois ...');
    // Fetch 100 messages (will be filtered and lowered up to max amount requested)
    message.channel.fetchMessages({
      limit: amount,
    }).then((messages) => {
      if (user) {
        const filterBy = user ? user.id : Client.user.id;
        messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);
      }
      message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
    });

    var purge = new Discord.RichEmbed()

      .setAuthor(`Suppression de ${amount} Messages dans le salon ${message.channel.name}`)
      .setFooter("Requête par " + message.member.user.tag, message.member.user.avatarURL)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor(0xF03434)

    message.channel.send(purge).then(message => {
      message.react('')
      client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        // on vérifie que ce soit bien la bonne réaction et on ne compte pas celui du bot
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id !== client.user.id) {
          message.delete()
        }
      })
    });
  }
}
```

What I would like is that at the level of the 'final' embed, when it tells me that the purge has been done, there is a reaction '' and when we click it removes the message.
The problem is that the current code removes all the embed of the same type.

Comment: Did you try to log what message is? (for example). To see what is happening. Don't name the variable by the same btw, change `message` to `msg` or anything else in the `.then` because it's confusing. Are you sure the embed message are not removed by your purge?

Comment: I can't test right now, but I'm not sure how Discord will behave if you add several `client.on`.

Comment: Hi, thanks @JackRed ! I did different tests to target the problem, it's not just the purge because for exemple in this in this "configuration" :
`
<embed>
message 1
message 2
message 3
<embed>
`
If I click on the reaction of the first embed, it also removes the second, and does not delete anything else ...

Comment: After trying to replace "msg", the problem remains the same ...

Comment: I have an error

(node: 10752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at item.request.gen.end (/Users/jeremy/Desktop/BERRYBOT/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:85:15)
    at then (/Users/jeremy/Desktop/BERRYBOT/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal / process / next_tick.js: 68: 7)
(node: 10752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated from the inside of the outside world, but it was not handled by .catch (). (rejection id: 14)
[...]

Comment: changing message to msg wasn't suppose to fix the problem, it's for comprehension. Naming different variable with the same name in nested funtion is confusing and doesn't help with the debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I click on the reaction of the first embed, it also removes the second, and does not delete anything else...

Attaching a listener to the client's [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event is what's causing this; *any* reaction emits this event, and your code is executed for each one after a single purge. As long as the reaction is  and the user isn't the client, [`Message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) will be called on `message`.

> ```js
> (node: 10752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
>     at item.request.gen.end (/Users/jeremy/Desktop/BERRYBOT/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:85:15)
>     at then (/Users/jeremy/Desktop/BERRYBOT/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal / process / next_tick.js: 68: 7)
> (node: 10752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated from the inside of the outside world, but it was not handled by .catch (). (rejection id: 14)
> ```

After adding that reaction that deletes the wrong message, it no longer exists. When you try to delete it again, this error will be thrown.

Furthermore, your code isn't waiting for the messages to be purged before sending the reply. Because of this, the message can be sent *before* and subsequently deleted by the [`TextChannel.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) call. Then, when you try to react to the same message via [`Message.react()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=react), your error is thrown because it no longer exists.

To make sure the code is executed in the proper order, make sure you're using your [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) chains properly, or utilize the beauty of [async/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

---

Reorganizing the code, still using `then()` methods:

```js
message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: amount })
  .then(fetchedMessages => {
    const filterBy = user ? user.id : Client.user.id;
    const toPurge = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);

    message.channel.bulkDelete(toPurge)
      .then(deletedMessages => {
        var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setAuthor(`Suppression de ${deletedMessages.size} Messages dans le salon ${message.channel.name}`)
          .setFooter(`Requête par ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.avatarURL)
          .setTimestamp()
          .setColor(0xF03434)

        message.channel.send(embed)
          .then(reply => {
            reply.react('');

            const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id !== client.user.id;
            reply.createReactionCollector(filter, { maxMatches: 1 })
              .on('collect', () => reply.delete());
          });
      });
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Alternatively, using [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```js
// You must define your callback function as async to use the 'await' keyword! It should look like...
// async (client, message, args) => { ... }

try {
  const fetchedMessages = await message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: amount });

  const filterBy = user ? user.id : Client.user.id;
  const toPurge = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);

  const deletedMessages = await message.channel.bulkDelete(toPurge);

  var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`Suppression de ${deletedMessages.size} Messages dans le salon ${message.channel.name}`)
    .setFooter(`Requête par ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.avatarURL)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor(0xF03434)

  const reply = await message.channel.send(embed)
  await reply.react('');

  const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id !== client.user.id;
  reply.createReactionCollector(filter, { maxMatches: 1 })
    .on('collect', async () => await reply.delete());
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

You'll notice this code is using [ReactionCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector)s as opposed to attaching listeners to the `messageReactionAdd` event. The former are meant for this usage and will prevent memory leaks. Also, I've changed some of the variable names to make the code easier to read and understand. A few other very minor improvements are present as well.